Python Script Works from Command Line but Fails When Called from C# in IIS
I have a MVC application written in C# and hosted on IIS. In my C# code, I am trying to call a Python script to access the Scopus website and retrieve user information. The Python script works perfectly when run from the command line, but when I call it from my C# code, it throws an error. I face some permission problem so I manually create some folders (pip,python...) and give the permission to IIS/user.
Error in python script: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\inetpub\site\scopus.py", line 15, in <module>
    verify_success(sb)
  File "C:\inetpub\site\scopus.py", line 9, in verify_success
    sb.assert_element('//span[contains(text(), "Author Search")]', timeout=30)
  File "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\seleniumbase\fixtures\base_case.py", line 9428, in assert_element
    self.wait_for_element_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\seleniumbase\fixtures\base_case.py", line 8853, in wait_for_element_visible
    return page_actions.wait_for_element_visible(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\seleniumbase\fixtures\page_actions.py", line 496, in wait_for_element_visible
    timeout_exception(NoSuchElementException, message)
  File "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\seleniumbase\fixtures\page_actions.py", line 254, in timeout_exception
    raise exc(msg)
seleniumbase.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: 
 Element {//span[contains(text(), "Author Search")]} was not present after 30 seconds!


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\inetpub\site\scopus.py", line 24, in <module>
    verify_success(sb)
  File "C:\inetpub\site\scopus.py", line 9, in verify_success
    sb.assert_element('//span[contains(text(), "Author Search")]', timeout=30)
  File "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\seleniumbase\fixtures\base_case.py", line 9428, in assert_element
    self.wait_for_element_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\seleniumbase\fixtures\base_case.py", line 8853, in wait_for_element_visible
    return page_actions.wait_for_element_visible(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\seleniumbase\fixtures\page_actions.py", line 496, in wait_for_element_visible
    timeout_exception(NoSuchElementException, message)
  File "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\seleniumbase\fixtures\page_actions.py", line 254, in timeout_exception
    raise exc(msg)
seleniumbase.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: 
 Element {//span[contains(text(), "Author Search")]} was not present after 30 seconds!


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\inetpub\site\scopus.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise Exception("Detected!")
Exception: Detected!


Python code
from seleniumbase import SB
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import json

def verify_success(sb):
    sb.assert_element('//span[contains(text(), "Author Search")]', timeout=10)
    sb.sleep(3)

userId = sys.argv[1]

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.uc_open_with_reconnect(f"https://www.scopus.com/authid/detail.uri?authorId={userId}", 3)
    try:
        verify_success(sb)
    except Exception:
        if sb.is_element_visible('input[value*="Verify"]'):
            sb.uc_click('input[value*="Verify"]')
        else:
            sb.uc_gui_click_captcha()
        try:
            verify_success(sb)
        except Exception:
            raise Exception("Detected!")
    finally:
        page_source = sb.get_page_source()
        document = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
        citations_node = document.select_one("div[data-testid='metrics-section-citations-count'] span[data-testid='unclickable-count']")
        documents_node = document.select_one("div[data-testid='metrics-section-document-count'] span[data-testid='unclickable-count']")
        hindex_node = document.select_one("div[data-testid='metrics-section-h-index'] span[data-testid='unclickable-count']")
        name_node = document.select_one("h1[data-testid='author-profile-name'] strong")
        institute_node = document.select_one("span[data-testid='authorInstitute']")
        scopus_information = {
            "CitationsNumber": int(citations_node.text.replace(",", "") if citations_node else "0"),
            "Documents": int(documents_node.text if documents_node else "0"),
            "HIndex": int(hindex_node.text if hindex_node else "0"),
            "Name": name_node.text.strip() if name_node else "",
            "Institute": institute_node.text.strip() if institute_node else ""
        }
        print(json.dumps(scopus_information, indent=4))

c# code :

public class ScopusInformation
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public int? CitationsNumber { get; set; }
    public int? Documents { get; set; }
    public int? HIndex { get; set; }
    public string? Institute { get; set; }
    public string? ScopusId { get; set; }
}
public interface IScopusService
{
    Task<ScopusInformation?> GetArticlesForUser(string userId);
}
public class ScopusServiceUsingPython(ILogger<ScopusService> logger) : IScopusService
{
  public async Task<ScopusInformation?> GetArticlesForUser(string userId)
    {
        string cmd = "py";
        var result2 = await DoCmdAsync(cmd, $"scopus.py {userId}");
        ScopusInformation? r2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ScopusInformation>(result2);
        return r2;
    }
 private async Task<string> DoCmdAsync(string cmd, string args)
    {
        logger.LogWarning("DoCmd in python script {cmd} {args}", cmd, args);
        try
        {
            // First, ensure required modules are installed
            await EnsurePythonModulesAsync(cmd, new[] { "seleniumbase", "beautifulsoup4", "pyautogui" });

            var start = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = cmd, // cmd is full path to python.exe
                Arguments = args, // args is path to .py file and any cmd line args
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            using var process = new Process { StartInfo = start };
            process.Start();

            var outputTask = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
            var errorTask = process.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();

            await Task.WhenAll(outputTask, errorTask);

            string result = await outputTask;
            string error = await errorTask;

            if (!process.WaitForExit(30000)) // 30 seconds timeout
            {
                process.Kill();
                throw new TimeoutException("Python script execution timed out after 30 seconds.");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
            {
                logger.LogWarning("Error in python script: {error}", error);
            }

            logger.LogWarning("Result in python script: {result}", result);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogWarning("Exception in python script: {ex}", ex.ToString());
            return "";
        }
    }

    private async Task EnsurePythonModulesAsync(string pythonPath, string[] modules)
    {
        foreach (var module in modules)
        {
            logger.LogWarning("Checking Python module: {module}", module);
            var checkStart = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = pythonPath,
                Arguments = $"-c \"import {module}\"",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            using var checkProcess = new Process { StartInfo = checkStart };
            checkProcess.Start();
            if (!checkProcess.WaitForExit(10000)) // 10 seconds timeout
            {
                checkProcess.Kill();
                throw new TimeoutException($"Checking for Python module {module} timed out.");
            }

            if (checkProcess.ExitCode != 0)
            {
                logger.LogWarning("Installing missing Python module: {module}", module);
                var installStart = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = pythonPath,
                    Arguments = $"-m pip install {module}",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                };

                using var installProcess = new Process { StartInfo = installStart };
                installProcess.Start();

                var outputTask = installProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
                var errorTask = installProcess.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();

                if (await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(outputTask, errorTask), Task.Delay(300000)) == Task.Delay(300000)) // 5 minutes timeout
                {
                    installProcess.Kill();
                    throw new TimeoutException($"Installation of Python module {module} timed out after 5 minutes.");
                }

                string output = await outputTask;
                string error = await errorTask;

                if (installProcess.ExitCode != 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Failed to install Python module {module}: {error}");
                }

                logger.LogWarning("Successfully installed Python module: {module}", module);
                logger.LogWarning("Installation output: {output}", output);
            }
            else
            {
                logger.LogWarning("Python module {module} is already installed.", module);
            }
        }
    }
}


Does it work if you run the c# code outside IIS?

Yes, it works when the C# code is run as a console application.

Please ensure that the IIS user account has read and write permissions to the folders where Python, its dependencies, and Selenium drivers are installed. also, ensure that the IIS user has the necessary permissions to access and control web browsers.

I regenerate this error in a C# console application, and it was bouncing sometimes generate the error, and sometimes it works with 0s data, and sometimes it works correctly
I just refine the numbers in your python script to make sure it will work fine, and then it works every time
scopus.py
from seleniumbase import SB
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import json

def verify_success(sb):
    sb.sleep(15) # give it some time to load the data
    sb.assert_element('//span[contains(text(), "Author Search")]', timeout=10)

userId = sys.argv[1]

with SB(uc=True) as sb:
    sb.uc_open_with_reconnect(f"https://www.scopus.com/authid/detail.uri?authorId={userId}", 10) # increase numbe of reconnect to 
    try:
        verify_success(sb)
    except Exception:
        if sb.is_element_visible('input[value*="Verify"]'):
            sb.uc_click('input[value*="Verify"]')
        else:
            sb.uc_gui_click_captcha()
        try:
            verify_success(sb)
        except Exception:
            raise Exception("Detected!")
    finally:
        page_source = sb.get_page_source()
        document = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
        citations_node = document.select_one("div[data-testid='metrics-section-citations-count'] span[data-testid='unclickable-count']")
        documents_node = document.select_one("div[data-testid='metrics-section-document-count'] span[data-testid='unclickable-count']")
        hindex_node = document.select_one("div[data-testid='metrics-section-h-index'] span[data-testid='unclickable-count']")
        name_node = document.select_one("h1[data-testid='author-profile-name'] strong")
        institute_node = document.select_one("span[data-testid='authorInstitute']")
        scopus_information = {
            "CitationsNumber": int(citations_node.text.replace(",", "") if citations_node else "0"),
            "Documents": int(documents_node.text.replace(",", "") if documents_node else "0"),  # the fomate numbers with ,
            "HIndex": int(hindex_node.text.replace(",", "") if hindex_node else "0"),           # they fomat numbers with ,
            "Name": name_node.text.strip() if name_node else "",
            "Institute": institute_node.text.strip() if institute_node else ""
        }
        print(json.dumps(scopus_information, indent=4))

program.cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text.Json;

var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
{
    builder.AddConsole();
});
var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ScopusServiceUsingPython>();
logger.LogInformation("Start logging");

IScopusService service = new ScopusServiceUsingPython(logger);

Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var info = await service.GetArticlesForUser("57221186307");
stopwatch.Stop();
  
Console.WriteLine("Result on C#");
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(info));
Console.WriteLine($"finished in :{stopwatch.Elapsed}");
Console.ReadKey();



public class ScopusInformation
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public int? CitationsNumber { get; set; }
    public int? Documents { get; set; }
    public int? HIndex { get; set; }
    public string? Institute { get; set; }
    public string? ScopusId { get; set; }
}
public interface IScopusService
{
    Task<ScopusInformation?> GetArticlesForUser(string userId);
}
public class ScopusServiceUsingPython(ILogger<ScopusServiceUsingPython> logger) : IScopusService
{
    public async Task<ScopusInformation?> GetArticlesForUser(string userId)
    {
        string cmd = "python";
        var result2 = await DoCmdAsync(cmd, $"scopus.py {userId}");
        ScopusInformation? r2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ScopusInformation>(result2);
        return r2;
    }
    private async Task<string> DoCmdAsync(string cmd, string args) 
    {
        logger.LogWarning("DoCmd in python script {cmd} {args}", cmd, args);
        try
        {
            // First, ensure required modules are installed
            await EnsurePythonModulesAsync(cmd, new[] { "seleniumbase", "beautifulsoup4", "pyautogui" });

            var start = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = cmd, // cmd is full path to python.exe
                Arguments = args, // args is path to .py file and any cmd line args
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            using var process = new Process { StartInfo = start };
            process.Start();

            var outputTask = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
            var errorTask = process.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();

            await Task.WhenAll(outputTask, errorTask);

            string result = await outputTask;
            string error = await errorTask;

            if (!process.WaitForExit(30000)) // 30 seconds timeout
            {
                process.Kill();
                throw new TimeoutException("Python script execution timed out after 30 seconds.");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
            {
                logger.LogWarning("Error in python script: {error}", error);
            }

            logger.LogWarning("Result in python script: {result}", result);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogWarning("Exception in python script: {ex}", ex.ToString());
            return "";
        }
    }

    private async Task EnsurePythonModulesAsync(string pythonPath, string[] modules)
    {
        foreach (var module in modules)
        {
            logger.LogWarning("Checking Python module: {module}", module);
            var checkStart = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = pythonPath,
                Arguments = $"-c \"import {module}\"",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            using var checkProcess = new Process { StartInfo = checkStart };
            checkProcess.Start();
            if (!checkProcess.WaitForExit(10000)) // 10 seconds timeout
            {
                checkProcess.Kill();
                throw new TimeoutException($"Checking for Python module {module} timed out.");
            }

            if (checkProcess.ExitCode != 0)
            {
                logger.LogWarning("Installing missing Python module: {module}", module);
                var installStart = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = pythonPath,
                    Arguments = $"-m pip install {module}",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                };

                using var installProcess = new Process { StartInfo = installStart };
                installProcess.Start();

                var outputTask = installProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
                var errorTask = installProcess.StandardError.ReadToEndAsync();

                if (await Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(outputTask, errorTask), Task.Delay(300000)) == Task.Delay(300000)) // 5 minutes timeout
                {
                    installProcess.Kill();
                    throw new TimeoutException($"Installation of Python module {module} timed out after 5 minutes.");
                }

                string output = await outputTask;
                string error = await errorTask;

                if (installProcess.ExitCode != 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Failed to install Python module {module}: {error}");
                }

                logger.LogWarning("Successfully installed Python module: {module}", module);
                logger.LogWarning("Installation output: {output}", output);
            }
            else
            {
                logger.LogWarning("Python module {module} is already installed.", module);
            }
        }
    }
}

here is the result on my Windows computer, it will take around 41 seconds to scrap the data with using this numbers
info: ScopusServiceUsingPython[0]
      Start logging
warn: ScopusServiceUsingPython[0]
      DoCmd in python script python scopus.py 57221186307
warn: ScopusServiceUsingPython[0]
      Checking Python module: seleniumbase
warn: ScopusServiceUsingPython[0]
      Python module seleniumbase is already installed.
warn: ScopusServiceUsingPython[0]
      Checking Python module: beautifulsoup4
warn: ScopusServiceUsingPython[0]
      Installing missing Python module: beautifulsoup4
warn: ScopusServiceUsingPython[0]
      Successfully installed Python module: beautifulsoup4
warn: ScopusServiceUsingPython[0]
      Installation output: Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\abram\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (4.12.3)
      Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in c:\users\abram\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python310\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4) (2.6)

warn: ScopusServiceUsingPython[0]
      Checking Python module: pyautogui
warn: ScopusServiceUsingPython[0]
      Python module pyautogui is already installed.
warn: ScopusServiceUsingPython[0]
      Result in python script: {
          "CitationsNumber": 104352,
          "Documents": 1522,
          "HIndex": 136,
          "Name": "Smith, John R.",
          "Institute": ""
      }

Result on C#
{"Name":"Smith, John R.","CitationsNumber":104352,"Documents":1522,"HIndex":136,"Institute":"","ScopusId":null}
finished in :00:00:41.4798995


Thank you @Ibram Reda for your effort; however, this solution does not work in a web application scenario. I got same error.
